# How to make Internet Explorer show the loading status indicator (spinning circle) when the loading page is in an individual frame?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-11, frames

I am working with a couple web applications, and one of them does not show the "spinning circle" status indicator in Internet Explorer when posting back a form.  When navigating from one page to another, the indicator works; it always seems to work on the second application.

It took me awhile to figure out the difference, but it is because the first application uses frames.  Navigating from page-to-page reloads the entire frameset, but a postback to any given webform only loads that frame.  In this instance, IE 11 does not provide any status indicator.  This is a problem on one specific form that does significant server-side processing--from a user perspective, you cannot tell that the form was even submitted.

Is there any way to force IE to show the status indicator in this scenario?  Alternately, I can use Javascript on submission to show some "Please wait..." type message.  I'd like to avoid that, as it is inconsistent with the rest of the application.  Thanks!

Here is a simple jsFiddle showing a simple iframe of CNN.  Notice that if you click links within that iframe, IE11 will show no status indicator that lets you know it is loading (normally the spinning circle on the tab).

https://jsfiddle.net/huokzjad/1/

Code:

```
<body>
<iframe src="http://cnn.com/" style="width: 90%; height: 300px;"></iframe>
</body>
```

Note that Firefox shows the loading status indicator properly.

Answer (score 0):

Already posted this as a possible option in the question, but will include as my own answer:

As a workaround, you could have a hidden `div` with a "loading" type message.  Upon submission, show the `div` using Javascript.